# Someone said they have my ip and my internal ip. They threaten to post it on the internet. What should I do?

Tags: ip, internet

They threatened me with a “I have your up and your internal up. I’m going to send it on the internet unless you do exactly as I say” what should I do? I’m doing what they say but I’m petrified.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a few other questions here. The short answer is "do nothing". It does not matter if your IPs are "posted" to the Internet (whatever that means).

Comment: As for your internal IP, if someone has the ability to do something bad with it, then they also have the ability to discover it on their own anyway. So, you can treat this "threat" as someone saying "I'm going to tell everyone your middle name!"

Comment: @schroeder The question you linked as duplicate does not mention 'private' or 'internal' anywhere in the question or answers. Anyone looking for the answer to this question won't find their answer there. This question is about one's internal IP address, which people are sometimes indeed afraid of leaking through WebRTC (albeit for different reasons than OP). I'm not sure it's really a duplicate, at least not with a comprehensive answer that explains the difference and how it doesn't matter if someone gets it aside from using it as fingerprinting datapoint.

Comment: @Luc this is about the internal and external ip.

Comment: @sk please do not vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 2):

> They threatened me with a “I have your up and your internal up. I’m going to send it on the internet unless you do exactly as I say” what should I do? I’m doing what they say but I’m petrified.

Ignore them and stop doing what they say!

Your public IP is not secret. Your internal IP is not unique. Ensure your OS is fully patched, and that you don't have any unwanted software installed on your computers. Move on.

There isn't really anything much you can glean from knowing a public IP. Sure, you can do denial of service attacks, but that will lead to you not being able to access the internet for a while, which is probably not too dramatic.

Comment: Point excellently made, anyone who gets you to load, say, an image they have on their server has your external "unique" IP. This might be useful as evidence in a criminal investigation, but for a hacker it is pretty useless if everything is updated properly, except for maybe temporarily blocking your internet. Your internal IP sais nothing if they're not already in your network.